# Using byte arrays as parameters for constructor: compiler error due to not found arguments

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have a specific problem regarding constructor and parameters.

I used byte[] arrays as parameters for my object constructor. My object class compiles just fine, but the test class has an error which i cannot figure out. 
I use the right parameters in the test class, but the compiler says there aren't any arguments in the constructor. It's propably just me not seeing the flaw, but i am pretty despirate over this one.

Thank you in advance!

Compiler-Error:

```
CubeTest.java:6: error: constructor Cube in class Cube cannot be applied to given types;
    Cube test = new Cube();
                ^
required: byte[],byte[],byte[],byte[],byte[],byte[]
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

The Cube class:

```
class Cube{
//declare arrays
private byte[] f;
private byte[] r;
private byte[] u;
private byte[] b; 
private byte[] l; 
private byte[] d; 
//
//
//
//constructor
public Cube(byte[] f, byte[] r, byte[] u, byte[] b, byte[] l, byte[] d){


    this.f = new byte[9];
    this.r = new byte[9];
    this.u = new byte[9];
    this.b = new byte[9];
    this.l = new byte[9];
    this.d = new byte[9];


    //fill this.f 
    for(int i = 0, n = 0; i < 9 && n < 9; i++, n++){
        this.f[i] = f[n];
    }
    //fill this.r 
    for(int i = 0, n = 0; i < 9 && n < 9; i++, n++){
        this.r[i] = r[n];
    }
    //fill this.u 
    for(int i = 0, n = 0; i < 9 && n < 9; i++, n++){
        this.u[i] = u[n];
    }
    //fill this.b 
    for(int i = 0, n = 0; i < 9 && n < 9; i++, n++){
        this.b[i] = b[n];
    }
    //fill this.l 
    for(int i = 0, n = 0; i < 9 && n < 9; i++, n++){
        this.l[i] = l[n];
    }
    //fill this.d 
    for(int i = 0, n = 0; i < 9 && n < 9; i++, n++){
        this.d[i] = d[n];
    }
}
}
```

The test class:

```
class CubeTest{
public static void main(String args[]){
    //f, r, u, b, l, d
    //1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    //create such arrays
    byte[] f = new byte[9];
    byte[] r = new byte[9];
    byte[] u = new byte[9];
    byte[] b = new byte[9];
    byte[] l = new byte[9];
    byte[] d = new byte[9];
    //fill arrays
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        f[i] = 1;
        r[i] = 2;   
        u[i] = 3;
        b[i] = 4;
        l[i] = 5;
        d[i] = 6;
    }
    //create Cube named test
    Cube test = new Cube(f, r, u, b, l, d);
    //
}
}
```

Comment: The error comes from this statement :  `Cube test = new Cube();` but you don't do this in the shown code. Check your actual code and recompile it, it should work as your constructor invocation respects the parameters specified in the constructor.

Comment: @davidxxx this is my problem: i dont do this in my code, i don't even to this in line 6, but the compiler tells me :/

Comment: Hmm. You have probably something you don't see : try to open your CubeTest class with another text editor and  check its content. Then ensure you compile this class and not a copy of it for example.

Comment: Your code as presented compiles and executes fine.  Your issue lies with something not shown.  http://rextester.com/SKY64011

Comment: thank you guys! i didn't even know the rextester page, i will use it in the future. i will try it with another editor.

Comment: I fixed it the way you told me, thank you very much! have a nice day.

Comment: If you really posted the correct code then you forgot to save your files or auto compile for your projects is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a default constructor too in your class Cube.
When you declare a custom constructor Java compiler doesn't create a default one.

Comment: but the problem is this dubious compiler error: i don't even use the default constructor, but the compiler tells me so (which is in my opinon wrong)

Comment: What happen if you add a default constructor? Do you still get that error?